# When does entity framework actually make the call to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have read a few other posts here but i'm not sure I'm quite satisified yet...

Take the following:

```
class Whatever
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Messages can relate to messages through replies
        /// </summary>
        public virtual IList<FieldMessage> FieldMessages { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int UnreadMessageCount
        {
            get
            {
                if( this.FieldMessages == null )
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                return this.FieldMessages.Where(x => x.Read == false).Count();
            }
        }
}
```

This is an entity framework class...

My questions:

1. Does Entity framework lazy load those `virtual IList properties` or does it way for you to call it before doing that?
2. When you're in your view, and you're doing a loop over the list of Whatever objects... and each loop you call the `UnreadMessageCount`... I noticed that on the if statement, `this.FieldMessages` takes the entire 6300 entires which I can look at while debugging, and then does the `.Where` statement at gets the count... Is it really doing that? Or is it just because i'm debugging it?
3. Do you have a good article about when on earth Entity Framework actually makes the database calls... I need to avoid memory being filled up because this site is to be used by thousands making messages all the time.

Comment: As soon as you convert an `IQueryable` to something else, it makes a call to the database.

Comment: @DionV. No, as soon you enumerate the `IQueryable` or extract a single value from it (`Count()`, `First()`, ...). If you do: `var enu = Enumerable.Select(query, x => x)` no call will be made, until you do `enu.ToArray()` or `enu.Count()` or `enu.First()` or...

Comment: As soon as you enumerate the `IQueryable` the magic happens, it's deferred execution

Comment: @xanatos Isn't that converting it to `IEnumerable` and call `MoveNext()`?

Comment: @DionV. See expanded reply for example of converting the query to `IEnumerable` without executing it.

Comment: @DionV. No. There is no conversion there. `IQueriable` is already `IEnumerable`

Comment: @xanatos Yes, I knew that, my bad. Your point is valid.

Comment: How comes this.FieldMessages has 6300 objects in it and I can view them when debugging in this case?

Comment: When you view them while debugging, you have to press a button to force it to enumerate right? that is causing the execution while debugging

Comment: The debugger enumerates for you - if you go to the property you should see a message saying "expanding this property will enumerate the IEnumerable" - as soon as you do that, the DB will be hit

Comment: What I actually meant is, as long as you do nothing with it (i.e. enumerate over it, call `First()`, call `Count()`, etc.), it does not call to the database. I should've been more explicit there and you are all correct.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh.... that is bootiiifulll... Thanks guys!

Comment: I assume you already know about EF `.Include()` method to load navigation properties? I believe you must have a virtual property to override for lazy loading since the EF proxy will decorate your property with lazy load code. In this case loading actually happens when you first access the property. So in your case you can safely query the `DBSet` and not have any database calls until you enumerate the `IQueryable`, then the `FieldMessages` collection will not be loaded until something tries to access the property.

Answer (score 1):

A query is made as soon as you try to use the collection : call to `Count` property, iteration using an `IEnumerable` extension method or `foreach`, ...). The whole collection will be loaded at first use then the collection stays in the context.

When you try read values in the debugger, methods of the collection are called and the database is queried.

If `FieldMessages` contains 6300 entries then maybe you should avoid declaring the collection on `Whatever` class. Use the context and `FieldMessage`'s `DbSet` to query unread messages attached to a specific `Whatever` instance with unread state.

Comment: But that's how entity framework works... From what I read above, the 6300 entries are only collected because I was debugging it.